# Size of conjugacy classes in infinite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, conjugacy-classes

Let G be an infinite group wich is finitely generated.

Is that true that the size of all finite conjugacy classes is bounded?

What I know. If G is a finitely generated FC-group then it's true (follows from [this](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_and_FC_implies_FZ)). But if G isn't FC- or FZ-group, so it's center has an infinite index, then I don't see any problems to have conjugacy classes which sizes tends to infinity. But also I don't see any examples of it :-)

On the other hand Osin and Hull proved (see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1107.1826.pdf)) that there exists groups with finite number of conjugacy classes and that number of conjugacy classe may obey to almost any function. So it looks like an argument for existence a group which finite conjugacy classes are not bounded.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is no: there exists a 2-generated group, having finite conjugacy classes of unbounded size.

Indeed B.H. Neumann (1937) produced a 2-generated group $G$ with normal subgroups $(H_n)_{n\ge 5}$ such that $H_n\simeq \mathrm{Alt}_n$. Since $H_n$ has a conjugacy class of size growing to infinity (say, the set of 3-cycles), so does $G$ (its conjugacy class in $G$ is contained in $H_n$, hence is finite too — actually it's unchanged in $G$, if one looks at the construction).

Comment: I see the paper ''B. H. Neumann, Some remarks on infinite groups, Journ. London Math. Soc. 12 (1937) 120-127.'' but I don't see the theorem you are talking about. Can you please help with the reference?

Comment: @AndronickArutyunov this is the construction in the proof of Theorem 14 of this reference (well, to be precise, I should have said $(H_n)$ is indexed by odd numbers $\ge 5$ only, although it's not a real issue).

Comment: got it! Thank you, I have to think about that construction.

Comment: @YCor. If I remember well, by another theorem of Neumann, if $G$ is a finitely generated FC-group then the center of $G$ has finite index. Therefore Schur's Theorem forces that the derived subgroup of $G$ is finite, and so the size of the conjugacy class of $G$ is bounded. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @SalvatoreSiciliano Yes, my example is not an FC-group and as already mentioned, by the (immediate) fact you're mentioning, no f.g. FC-group yields an example. There's no requirement in the OP's question that all conjugacy classes are finite.

Answer (score 5):

The size of all conjugacy class of a group $G$ is bounded if and only if the derived subgroup $G^\prime$ of $G$ is finite.

This is a celebrated theorem of Neumann proved in the following paper:

B.H. Neumann: "Groups covered by permutable subsets", J. London
Math. Soc. bf 29 (1954), 236–248.

Comment: If G' isn't finite then there exist infinite conjugacy classes, sure. But I'm interested in a liitle bit other case. Group has infinite conjugacy classes. Is that true that the size of all finite (just finite!) classes is bounded?